# AnyTime date picker not working inside facebox model dialog

Tags: jquery, facebox, anytime

Below is the code I am using for facebox with AnyTime Date picker http://www.ama3.com/anytime/ DatePicker does not seem to show when placed inside facebox. I tried changing the z-index for AnyTime however it did not work. AnyTime date picker pops up on a normal jsp page.

Could any one pleasae let me know what might be the issue ? thanx

```
<html> 
<head> 


<SCRIPT language="javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></SCRIPT> 


<link href="facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/ 
css"/> 
<script src="facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


<script> 


jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox(); 

}) 


</script> 

<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='anytimec.css' 
title="Style"> 
<SCRIPT language="javascript" src='anytimec.js'></SCRIPT> 


</head> 


<body> 


<a href="#info" rel="facebox">text</a> 


<div id="info" > 


<form id="test"> 
<table> 
<td>Date</td> 
<td><input id="dateText" style="z-index:999;"/> 
<script type="text/javascript">AnyTime.picker( "test:dateText", 
{ format: "%e/%c/%Y", firstDOW: 6 } );</script> 
</td> 
</table> 
</form> 
</div> 


</body> 


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

when calling the picker function, it should be

```
AnyTime.picker( "dateText", { format: "%e/%c/%Y", firstDOW: 6 } );
```

which is the id of the input element you wish to use. AnyTime will then appear as a popup.

Answer (score 0):

AnyTime.picker( "test:dateText",  { format: "%e/%c/%Y", firstDOW: 6 } );

In the above code test:dateText is the id of the JSF field which is being generated. I noticed that when I use AnyTime picker with jQuery dialog the close button disappears, so I decided to use jQuery datepicker with AnyTime picker.

Thanks
Ayub